# Trying to modify the appearance of a description environment

Tags: color, lists, indentation, description, french

I have to do something like this but I don't know how to do it. I tried with `\newcommand` and `\newenvironment` but it seems that it's the wrong solution

[image]

if you have any idea please tell me.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution which employs the [enumitem](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) package and its `newlist` and `\setlist` macros to create a bespoke version, called `mydescription`, of the `description` environment. With this setup, the properties of the basic `description` environment are left untouched.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable document class
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=2.5cm]{geometry} % Set page parameters suitably
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{xcolor,lipsum}

\usepackage{enumitem}  % See https://www.ctan.org/pkg/enumitem
\newlist{mydescription}{description}{1}
\setlist[mydescription]{style=nextline,
                        font=\color{red}\bfseries,
                        % Tweak the next 4 options as needed:
                        labelindent=1cm, 
                        leftmargin =2cm,
                        rightmargin=1cm,
                        topsep     =3ex
                       }

\begin{document}
\setcounter{section}{4}  % Just for this example
\setcounter{subsection}{2}


\subsection{La chaîne du recyclage}

La chaîne du recyclage comporte différentes étapes:

\begin{mydescription}
\item[Étape 1 -- Collecte de déchets] 
  \lipsum[1][1-4]   % filler text
  
  \lipsum[1][5-10]  % more filler text
  
\item[Étape 2 -- Transformation] 

  \lipsum[2][1-4]
  
\item[Étape 3 -- Commercialisation et conservation] 

  \lipsum[2][1-4]

\end{mydescription}

En fin de vie, ces produits serons, peut être, jetés même si certains
d'entre eux pourraient être à récupérés et recylés.
\end{document}
```